# Import csv as list in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to import a csv file as a list:

```
file = open('curr.csv', 'rt')
f = file.read()
f = f.split(',')

print(f)
```

The csv file is only 'GBP, USD' so I want the list ['GBP', 'USD'].
However the result I get is:

```
['GBP', 'USD\n']
```

How do I stop \n from appearing on the last value?

Comment: Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip your lines,but as a pythonic way you can use [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for dealing with `csv` files :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('curr.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     print list(spamreader)
```

Note that this will return a nested list of your `csv` file rows if you just want the firs row in a list you can use `next()` method of `reader` object :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('curr.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     print spamreader.next()
```

And if you want the whole of your rows within a list you can use a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('curr.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     print [j for i in spamreader for j in i]
```

Comment: A valid answer, but seems a bit overkill for such a simple file.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Its the correct way for dealing with `csv` files. note that we are not here to just give a temporary solution to OP!

Comment: I agree with Kasra. Splitting around the string wouldn't be much shorter than 3 lines either while being a lot more fragile.

Comment: @Kasra There are various "correct ways" of dealing with `csv` files depending on the circumstances.  In this case, dealing with the `csv` module adds additional complexity around dealing with multiple lines.  Your answer, for example, gives `[['GBP', ' USD']]`, which isn't what the question asked for.  So in this case using a simpler approach can avoid some confusion.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Yeah i noted that. i gonna to edit the answer! thanks for attention!